# Average angle between a point on a sphere and the line of sight

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I want to know what the average angle is for a random point on a sphere with respect to our line of sight. I simulated it by doing the following [(Image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8viMP.png):

1. Randomly sample points on a surface of a sphere that come from a uniform distribution. See panel 1 in the attached figure.
2. For each point, find the angle, $\theta$ made with the vector $(x, y, z) = (1, 0, 0)$. The angles range from $0$ to $180$. See panel 2 in the figure.
3. The angles are symmetric about $90^\circ$, so for $\theta > 90^\circ$, return $180 - \theta$. e.g. all points at $78^\circ$ and $102^\circ$ will look like $78^\circ$. See panel 3 in the figure.
4. Find the mean of the distribution in panel 3. This gives $57^\circ$.

This is what I would expect: it is unlikely a point will be orientated at $0^\circ$ to our line of sight, and most likely a point will be at $90^\circ$, so the mean is likely to lie between $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$, but closer to $90^\circ$. My guess would have been $70^\circ$.

While I got the answer analytically, my question is how can I find this answer theoretically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The density of points at an angle $\theta$ with respect to some fixed direction is $f(\theta)=\sin\theta$. Thus the cumulative distribution function is $F(\theta)=1-\cos\theta$, and thus the mean angle is

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\frac\pi2\left(1-F(\theta)\right)\mathrm d\theta=\int_0^\frac\pi2\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta=\left[\sin\theta\right]^\frac\pi2_0=1-0=1\;.
\end{eqnarray}

In degrees, that’s $1\cdot\frac{180°}\pi\approx57.3°$, in agreement with your findings.

Comment: That all makes perfect sense. The one question I have is if _f_ (_t_) = sin _t_), the why is the CDF _F_ (_t_) = 1 - cos(_t_)?

Comment: @SeanMooney: The CDF is the integral of the PDF. In this case the integral from $0$, the least value:

$$
\int_0^\theta\sin\xi\mathrm d\xi=\left[-\cos\xi\right]^\theta_0=1-\cos\theta\;.
$$